# Chrome/Chromium addon to display tabs like Firefox when you have many tabs

Tags: chrome

Chromium 65.0.3325.162. I already use **tabli**.

With Firefox, any version, when I have > 100 tabs:

[image]

Instead, when I use Chrom(e|ium), any version, I get:

[image]

Is there any addon to display tabs bigger (so scrollable) with the favicon?

That way, it could be possible to select tab to move it and recognize them.

Comment: Some vertical tab add-ons / extensions might show 30-60 readable tabs at once, but they're pretty different from the standard tab bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure it out, installing the nice project :  [ungoogled-chromium](https://github.com/Eloston/ungoogled-chromium) and activate :

> Enable stacking in tab strip
>   Forces tabs to be stacked in the tab strip. Otherwise, they follow default behavior. – Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS, Android

via `chrome://flags` uri

> ```
> #enable-stacked-tab-strip
> ```

[image]

Interesting sentence from flags page:

> Trace label for navigation tracing
>   This is to be used in conjunction with the enable-navigation-tracing flag. Please select the label that best describes the recorded traces. This will choose the destination the traces are uploaded to. If you are not sure, select other. If left empty, no traces will be uploaded. – Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS, Android
>
> ```
> #trace-upload-url
> ```

[google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) seems like a mass spyware by default